# Using Pandas/NumPy to increase resolution

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to change the number of point in array, so  the new point y value will be the same value as the original point on the left side.

```
import numpy as np

def regularizeSeries1(x, y, M = 100):
    s0 = (x - x[0])
    s1 = np.linspace(0, max(s0), M + 1)
    z = np.empty(M)
    for i in range(M):
        z[i] = y[(s0 <= s1[i])][-1]
    return(z)

x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 5, 7,8 ,10])
y = np.array([0, 1, 3,4, 6, 7.5, 9])
M = 20
Z = regularizeSeries1(x, y, M)
```

How can I do it without loop using Pandas or numpy?

[[image]][1

Answer (score 0):

merge and fill the nan using pd.ffill

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
M = 20
x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 5, 7,8 ,10])
y = np.array([0, 1, 3,4, 6, 7.5, 9])
s1 = np.linspace(0, max(s0), M)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'x': s1}) 
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on='x', how='outer').sort_values(by='x').ffill().reset_index(drop=True) 
df3 = df3[df3['x'].isin(df2['x'])]
newX, newY = df3['x'], df3['y']
```